# Using FOR loop in VBA to run sql query multiple times

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

Am trying to run SQL query in for loop in VBA. following is my query which does not give any result rather gives #value error. Am new to VBA programming, if someone can please tell me what am doing wrong.

```
j = Ason - Strdt

For i = 0 To j

strSQL = "select SUM(isnull(round(debit_bal,2),0)) - SUM(isnull(round(credit_bal,2),0)) from VDetail where Act_Code between Starting_Account & "' and '" & Ending_Account & "' and V_Date between convert(VARCHAR(10),'01/01/2007',10) and  convert(VARCHAR(10),
& DateAdd(d, i, Strdt) & "',10) "

Set oRsSQL = oConSQL.Execute(strSQL)

sumv = oRsSQL.Fields(0).Value + sumv


Next i


get_balance = sumv
```

Strdt is the date from which i want it to start summing data and Ason is the date till which it should sum.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PS: i cannot add another column to database as its beyond my access

Comment: If  `Starting_Account` and `Ending_Account` are vba variable, you are missing some `'" & ` before `Starting _Account` and before `DateAdd...`

Comment: thanks for that, even after that it shows #value

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and see what the value of strSQL is when you you step  through with the debugger?

Comment: You are referencing Strdt in your SQL string. Again you are missing some string concatenation there.